# Use $(window).scroll function to jump to divs on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Im trying to mimic the functionality of this site https://moto360.motorola.com/
When you scroll down on that page it just jumps to the next "screen" and if you scroll up it jumps back up.

My JS is here :

```
var currentDiv = "Home";
var latestScroll = 0;
var scrollable = true;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#HomeLink").addClass("activeNav");
        $(".navLink").click(function(){
            $(".navLink").removeClass("activeNav");
            $(this).addClass("activeNav");
            var divID = $(this).attr("data-linkID");
            scrollTo(divID);
        });
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            console.log(scrollable);
            if (scrollable==true){
                var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (currentScroll > latestScroll){
                    scrollable = false;
                    //downscroll
                    if(currentDiv!="About"){
                        var nextDiv = $("#"+currentDiv).next()[0];
                        var nextDivID = $(nextDiv).attr("id");
                        scrollTo(nextDivID);
                    }
                }else{
                    scrollable = false;
                    //upscroll
                    if(currentDiv!="Home"){
                        var prevDiv = $("#"+currentDiv).prev()[0];
                        var prevDivID = $(prevDiv).attr("id");
                        scrollTo(prevDivID);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function scrollTo(divID){
        currentDiv = divID;
        var target = $("#"+divID);
        $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Do something after 2 seconds
            latestScroll = target.offset().top;
            scrollable = true;
        }, 2000);
    }
```

My problem is that once it starts scrolling it jumps to the next screen but then when the jQuery animate is running it registers more scrolls and then just keeps jumping. I've tried adding the boolean scrollable and even a timeout when setting that back to true but it still will jump at least twice.

HTML :

```
<div id="screens">
    <div class="screen" id="Home">
        <div id="logo">ZEPPA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="screen" id="Video">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="screen" id="Info">INFO</div>
    <div class="screen" id="About">ABOUT US</div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I cannot seem to find a way to get it to only register the scrolling once and then reset itself nicely.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a1cpx2cf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of a tested plugin like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Things will become more complicated when you start worrying about touch screen computers, mobile phones, kinetic scrolling (used in Apple laptops), transitions performance, fallback compatibility with old browsers, keyboard accessibility,  changes in the URL for each section, useful URLs for returning users or specific linking etc.

Using a tested script will always make things easier and will save you many headaches.

Comment: looks great Ill give it a shot later! I'm very open to using a plugin I just couldnt find one that fit